# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Adapter request's response is getting cached within the app

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

We have observed that an adapter request's response is getting cached within the app in a `cache.db` file.

Is there a way to avoid this? is there any configuration in worklight property file?

Comment: Can you edit the question with an example of the adapter response and of what is being cached?

Comment: As well as if you can provide any additional information, such as - is this a Hybrid app, or a Native app?

Comment: it's a native hybrid mix app and the whole response from adapter is getting cached in cached.db file.

Comment: So this is a Hybrid Worklight app with native pages?

Answer (score 0):

There is the following IBM Worklight technote: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM95421

> Sensitive data, such as usernames and passwords that are part of URLs,
>   is being stored in the iOS cache.db file in plain text.
>
> This issue can be worked around by using calls to
>   WL.Client.addGlobalHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache'); at
>   the appropriate places in the app code.  A call to
>   removeGlobalHeader() can be used to reverse the Cache-Control setting.

So:

1. You can try the above.
2. Also see my questions in the comments section of the question

In addition: there is a way to clear or manipulate this file via native code.
In the context of a Worklight application under the above assumption, [you will need to create a Cordova plug-in](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started/#cordova) that will do operations on this file.

See the following:

- [How to clear or manipulate cache.db data ios application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017624/how-to-clear-or-manipulate-cache-db-data-ios-application)
- [Sensitive Data stored in cache.db-wal file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668617/sensitive-data-stored-in-cache-db-wal-file)
- [Empty the cache programmatically in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581221/empty-the-cache-programmatically-in-ios)
- http://www.slideshare.net/securitylearnwordpress/hacking-and-securing-ios-applications

Comment: can you please let me know where exactly to add `WL.Client.addGlobalHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache'); ` in the code so that i can remove cache.

Comment: You can add it anywhere in the code. For example, before the adapter request. Please consult with the Worklight 6.1 user documentation.

Comment: About cache.db or about WL.Client.addGlobalHeader?

Comment: what is there in worklight docs related to this....and where can i found the docs for the same.

Comment: But what are you asking about?! cache.db, or WL.Client?? There is nothing I can find about cache.db; Search the user documentation for WL.Client and you'll find the docs for that API. Google.

Comment: Hi Idan , How to clear cache for CFURL, also let me know how to get final request sent to Worklight adapter ?